# I have hosted my webapi application on IIS Manager but it gives me the following error,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have hosted mywebapi application on IIS Manager. i just want to access it on my machines using IP Address but it gives me the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user in Permission of IIS.User name should be User and allow all the permission to User.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with your web.config file. Review it accurately again. Also make sure you use correct Application Pool when create your application in IIS. It should be something like ASP.NET v4.0

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by adding a single line code in web.config

```
     <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```